# Не создаются папки при создании volume docker

Tags: docker, mount

При создании тома командой:

```
 docker volume create [name_volume]
```

в директории /var/lib/docker/volumes не создается папка созданного тома. Но при запросе

```
  docker volume ls
```

созданный том отображается.
Также пробовал создать том в другой директории командой:

```
  docker volume create --driver local \
  --opt type=none \
  --opt device=[new_path] \
  --opt o=bind \
  [name_volume]
```

данная папка `[new_path]` осталась пустой. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

При пробросе папки как bind mount, например:

```
docker run -v /home/server:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx
```

если в папке */home/server* лежит файл tmpl.html, то при

```
docker exec nginx ls /usr/share/nginx/html
```

вижу, что в контейнере лежит только мой файл tmpl.html. При создании новых файлов в этой папке, они также появляются в контейнере. Соответственно, если папка */home/server* пустая, то при запуске контейнера в /usr/share/nginx/html тоже пусто. **Разве должны удаляться файлы контейнере?** Если создаю файл в контейнере, то он появляется в /home/server.

Если создаю том

```
    docker volume create --driver local \
  --opt type=none \
  --opt device=/home/server/ \
  --opt o=bind \
  srv
```

и если он **пустой**, то в него копируется содержимое папки из контейнера командой:

```
docker run -v srv:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx
```

Остальное поведение точно такое же, как у bind mount. Также, если запускаю контейнер следующим образом:

```
 docker run -v srv-new:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx
```

где srv-new не созданный (его нет в списке volumes) том, то в директории /var/lib/docker/volumes папки srv-new не создается, как я уже писал выше. Так же как и папки srv в директории /home/server/.
При вызове:

```
docker inspect srv-new
```

получаю:

```
[
{
    "CreatedAt": "2022-09-19T17:29:13Z",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": null,
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/srv-new/_data",
    "Name": "srv-new",
    "Options": null,
    "Scope": "local"
}
```

]

Если что то не правильно делаю, поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте примонтировать его к контейнеру и что-нибудь записать.

Comment: Дописал сверху.